# How to mock the session object to the route api/auth/session in NextAuth in a new Next.js 13 app directory in my Cypress test?

Tags: next.js, cypress, e2e-testing, next-auth, next.js13

I am currently using the new Next.js 13 app directory and next-auth for authentication. The session is generated server-side, so I can't access the session object in Cypress. I want to mock the session object in Cypress so that I can test my application's functionality without having to be logged in.

I have tried the following to mock the session object:

- Using `cy.intercept` to intercept the `/api/auth/session` route. However, this only intercepts the route from the client-side request, not the server-side request.
- Using the client-side `signIn` method from next-auth and supplying credentials (I am using credentials signIn). However, this didn't work either.
  I am hoping someone can help me figure out how to mock the session object in Cypress so that I can test my application's functionality.

Here are some additional details about my environment:

- I am using NextAuth v4.22.1
- I am using Next.js v13.4.4
- I am using Cypress v12.3.0

Comment: Hi, any update on this? Having very similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at msw. I use it a lot in every project.

https://mswjs.io/

Comment: Does it work for mocking server-side requests?

Comment: Yes. It works with everything that issue requests in both browser and NodeJS.

Comment: I can't find a good guide, unfortunately.